# Product of a sequence converging in distribution and a sequence converging in probability converges in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm working on the following problem and would appreciate any hints or solutions

> Suppose $X_n\to X$ in distribution and $Y_n\to 1$ in probability. 
>   Show that $X_nY_n\to X$ in distribution.

Here are my thoughts: $Y_n$ converging in probability to 1 means $P(1-\epsilon<Y_n<1+\epsilon)\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.  I would like to choose $\epsilon$ less than 1 so that we don't have to worry about multiplying any negative numbers to inequalities and then I want to use that to show that $P(X_nY_n\leq x) \to P(X\leq x)$.  I'm having trouble putting these two ideas together though, by somehow multiplying by $Y_n$.  I suspect this could also involve taking conditional probabilities.

Source: [Spring 1997](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Pre_2012_papers/Prob_Pre_2011.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
\begin{align}
&P(X_n(1+\epsilon) \le x)\ P(|Y_n - 1| < \epsilon)
\\
&\le P(X_n Y_n \le x)
\\
&\le P(X_n(1-\epsilon) \le x)\ P(|Y_n - 1| < \epsilon) + P(|Y_n - 1| > \epsilon)
\end{align}